# Is it possible to use IF(cond1 AND cond2,result,else result) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to do update query if the consecutive 5 column have 0 value. My first idea is:

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `count` = IF(`col1`=0.00 AND 
                 `col2`=0.00 AND 
                 `col3`=0.00 AND 
                 `col4`=0.00 AND 
                 `col5`=0.00,  count+1, count)
```

But I think using AND in IF condition isn't work. Any idea? Thanks before

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Using `if` with multiple `and` is valid..

Comment: already tried, but failed. Like i said using AND in IF condition isn't work

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what was the error?

Comment: Working for me check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae21e/1

Comment: My mistakes. Actually it works, just wrong at write the end statement.

Answer (score 3):

Using `AND` in an `IF` is perfectly valid, but as Grijesh suggets, using the condition in the `WHERE` clause is the usual way to do it.

Your query though shouldn't give any errors.

Comment: Perhaps. The question is not very clear. It could be read as "is using AND in IF valid?". In that case, it is a answer ;-).

Comment: Yes you are correct but OP's query is not correct because of  `count=if()`. My Vote to your answer is pending till you correct his if query. :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs Is it correct I am not sure because? can he do `=` assignment ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs I perform an experiment and I came to know you are correct Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this, if I am not wrong, it looks simple to me:

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET    `count`= `count` + 1
WHERE  `col1`=0.00 AND `col2`=0.00 AND 
       `col3`=0.00 AND `col4`=0.00 AND 
       `col5`=0.00;
```

**Edit**

And what @Bart Friederichs 's answer is correct AND/OR are valid in if()

`IF()` **works like:**  ( [**`IF()` function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) )

```
IF(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)
```

I perform below experiment, And according to this I believe your query will work. (*Its just my idea, I am not sure*)

```
mysql> SET  @a=IF(0 AND 1,5,3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

NOTE: You can do `=` and you can use AND/OR in IF() function.

Comment: That would be the way to normally do it yes, but OP's solution should work as well (just tested it and MySQL is not complaining).